# Criar links para os eventos criados no fullcalendar e abrir em um modal Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Colegas.

Estou usando o Fullcalendar em uma aplicação e os eventos consegui cadastrar usando o PHP/Mysql. Porém gostaria criar links  nesses eventos que aparecem no calendário e que ao clicar nesses links fossem direcionados para uma página específica com a descrição desses eventos. Isso é possível no Fullcalendar? Veja a imagem abaixo marcado em amarelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aproveitando, quero compartilhar com vocês esse link. Ele tem um exemplo de como fazemos para cadastrar, editar e excluir eventos no Fullcalendar usando o PHP/mysql e Bootstrap. [CRUD com PHP/Mysql no FullCalendar com Bootstrap](http://jamelbaz.com/tutos/integration-de-fullcalendar2-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Para que funcione, na tabela mysql vocês tem que respeitar a nomenclatura: title, start e description. Primeiro coloquei o modal do Bootstrap:

```
<div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E no Jquery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            height: 300,
            contentHeight: 360,
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: 'eventos.php',
            eventColor: '#dd6777',

            eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
            $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
            $('#fullCalModal').modal();
        }
        });
 });
</script>
```